# R Script pdf to excel using pdftools

Tags: r, excel, pdf

I am using pdftools to convert the pdf to excel. I want to extract the table values.The code below works perfectly but it pastes everything in rows(I mean the values are not separated in different coloumns- The only thing I want is the table as it is in the pdf(the data and values). . Can someone help with the code? Maybe we need a separator? I hope for some help!
3 images below:-
Excel output I get,Expected Excel Output and the PDF I am working with.

```
library(pdftools)
tx<-pdf_text("Path")
tx2<-strsplit(tx,"\n")
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(tx2,file="ds.xlsx")
```

Comment: You might like to have a look at the `pdftables` package to make this easier.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the pdf?

Comment: @AndrewGustar I looked into pdftables earlier-but its not completely free unfortunately.I wish to do this conversion everyday

Comment: @hpesoj626 I already uploaded the screenshot of the pdf file.

Comment: You could try splitting at multiple spaces - `tx3<-strsplit(tx2,"\\s{2,}")`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Error in strsplit(tx2, "\\s{2,}") : non-character argument

Comment: `tx2` might be a list. If so, use `unlist(tx2)` instead.

Comment: @AndrewGustar It still gives the same error

Comment: I don't know, @Bunty, but the converted pdf from the screenshot returns empty llists.

Comment: I don't think its this complicated. Just need to put a separator /split the text into columns.Its a normal text based pdf(as visible from screenshot-I cannot share the entire pdf file). I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this...

```
library(pdftools)
library(stringr)
library(xlsx)

tx <- pdf_text("Path")
tx2 <- unlist(str_split(tx, "[\\r\\n]+"))
tx3 <- str_split_fixed(str_trim(tx2), "\\s{2,}", 5)

write.xlsx(tx3, file="ds.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew. I receive the following output-https://imgur.com/a/xJsbj

Comment: Worth a try. It is going to be hard to get any further on this unless you can share the pdf file on here. You just need to examine carefully the structure of what comes out of each stage and try to work out a suitable way of splitting it.

Comment: @Bunty The problem might be in your `tx2` line - see amendment above. When I tried it on some dummy data the lines were split by `\r\n`, not just `\n`.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked now.Really appreciate your time and effort.